# Automatically generate tags from strings with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I need to -automatically- generate tags for a text string. In this case, I'll use this string:

```
var text = 'This text talks about loyalty in the Royal Family with Príncipe Charles';
```

My current implementation, generates the tags for words that are 6+ characters long, and it works fine.

```
words = (text).replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,function(str){return '';});
words = words.match(/\w{6,}/g);
console.log(words);
```

This will return:

```
["loyalty","Family","Prince","Charles"]
```

The problem is that sometimes, a tag should be a specific set of words. I need the result to be:

```
["loyalty","Royal Family","Príncipe Charles"]
```

That means, that the replace/match code should test for:

1. words that are 6 characters long (or more); and/or
2. if a set of words starts with an uppercase letter, those words should be joined together in the same array element. It doesn't matter if some of the words are less than 6 characters long - but at least one of them has to be 6+, e.g.: "Stop at The UK Guardián in London" should return ["The UK Guardián", "London"]

I'm obviously having trouble in the second requirement. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var text = 'This text talks about loyalty in the Royal Family with Prince Charles. Stop at The UK Guardian in London';

text.match(/(([A-Z]\w*\s*){2,})|(\w{6,})/g)
```

will return

```
["loyalty", "Royal Family ", "Prince Charles", "The UK Guardian ", "London"]
```

To fulfill the second requirement, it's better to run another regexp over the matches found:

```
var text = 'This is a Short Set Of Words about the Royal Family'

matches = text.match(/(([A-Z]\w*\s*){2,})|(\w{6,})/g)
matches.filter(function(m) {
    return m.match(/\w{6,}/)
});
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it will also match `'I Am Cool'`, which is not a match as none of the words have >= 6 characters.

Comment: +1, good job with that update.  This seems to work just as the OP wants :-)

Comment: great solution! just one important thing, the solution should consider special characters. For example, "Princé Hermione" is returning ["Hermione"]; and "superhábilmente" is returning ["superh","bilmente"]

Comment: @andufo: that's true. `\w`, `\d` and friends are not unicode-aware in javascript (what a shame!)

Comment: @thg435 any ideas on how to make it work around it? the texts are mostly in spanish :s

Comment: @andufo: you could replace `\w` with an explicit character class, like `[\wéáè]`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's an idea.  This is probably not the very best way to do this, but it might be a good start for you.

In order matching strings like `Royal Family` and `Prince Charles`, or perhaps even `The United Kingdom`, you could write a regex that looks for a succession of words starting with a capital letter in succession.

This might look like this: `(A-Z(a-z){5,}* )+`

You could then use the replace function to generate a new string with the matches removed and then use your original regex to match single words of a minimum length.

**Update:** In response to the comment about the other users answer, I have added the `{5,}` modifier to indicate a capital letter followed by five or more lower case letters and a space, one or more times.